# BlankCordovaApp first run configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to create a **BlankCordovaApp** with visual studio 2013 and installed all the pre-requests as far as I know but there is still errors and warnings in output window.
I've done configurations for system environment so VS could find all it's needs.
What's this error about and how could I find and guidance for it? Thank you

```
Error   15  The command ""C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Windows-

AnyCPU" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "BlankCordovaApp2" --language "en-US" "--AnyCPU"" exited with 

code 1. C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets 96  5
```

BlankCordovaApp2

When I click on error VS shows these lines of codes

```
<Exec Command='"$(AppData)\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "$(Platform)" --configuration "$(Configuration)" --projectDir . --projectName "$(ProjectName)" --language "$(LangName)" "--$(Platform.Substring(8))"' Condition=" '@(BuildMDACpuSpecificPlatform)' != '' " CustomErrorRegularExpression="$(MDACustomErrorRegEx)" StdOutEncoding="UTF-8" StdErrEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error Code 1 almost always suggests that the Windows SDK is missing. To fix that, do the following:

In Control Panel, choose Programs and Features. Select Visual Studio 2013 from the list, and then choose Change. In the Visual Studio setup window, choose Modify. In the features list, ensure that these 2 options are check marked:

```
Tools for Maintaining Store apps for Windows 8

Windows Phone 8.0 SDK
```

Once you're done installing these packages, try building the app again, the problem should have been resolved.

Comment: I checked these two items and they were marked already. I'm gonna try re-install them maybe fix the problem.

Comment: Good replacement for Cordova programming on VisaulStudio. www.cshtml5.com